# Proving that a relation is symmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, relations, equivalence-relations

I need to show that $x \sim y$ if $x=2y$. I started off by assuming that $x,y \in R$. Since $x=2y$, $y=x/2$. Since $y \neq 2x$, $\sim$ is not symmetric. Could I approach the problem is this way?

Comment: It is symmetric if $x=y=0$.  But not for other $x,y \in \mathbb R$

Comment: @Henry : A relation being symmetric must hold in all cases (i.e., for all $x,y$: $x\sim y \Rightarrow y\sim x$). One counterexample and the relation is not symmetric.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can. Note that all you have to do is to find a pair of real numbers $x,y$ such that $x \sim y$ but $y \nsim x$. Take $x = 2, y = 1$.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are correct. The relation is not symmetric.

Hope this helps. Ask anything if not clear :)